# Find the coordinates of a 3D point given the euclidean distance and rotation to another known point

Tags: python, math, rotation, quaternions, coordinate-systems

Imagine a 3D point (Point 1) with coordinates to origin `x,y,z=1,2,3` and quaternion rotation values to origin: `w,x,y,z=0.8,0.1,0.1,0.1` (which can be converted to rotation matrices). Further, imagine another 3D point (Point 2) that has a known euclidean distance from Point 1 equal to `2`. You also know the quaternion rotation from Point 2 to Point 1 which is equal to `w,x,y,z=0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5` (can also be converted to rotation matrices). Using this information, how can you find the x,y,z coordinates of Point 2?

I am going to code this out using python, so if you have a suggestion for how to do so as well, that would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import numpy as np
import quaternion 
p1_coords = [1,2,3]
p1_rot_to_origin = np.quaternion(0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
p2_rot_to_p1 = np.quaternion(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Using RVIZ I get:

I have tried illustrating it using rviz. Code:

```py
class TestAnimator(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('TestAnimator')
        self.tf_broadcaster = tf2_ros.TransformBroadcaster(self)   
        
        # Ros 2
        self.timer = self.create_timer(1, self.timer_callback)
                    
    def timer_callback(self):      
        p1 = TransformStamped()
        p1.header.frame_id = 'origin' # 
        p1.child_frame_id = f'Point_1'
        p1.transform.translation = Vector3(x=1., y=2., z=3.)
        p1.transform.rotation = Quaternion(w=0.8, x=0.1, y=0.1, z=0.1)
        self.tf_broadcaster.sendTransform(p1)
        
        p2 = TransformStamped()
        p2.header.frame_id = f'Point_1' # 'test_frame'
        p2.child_frame_id = f'Point_2'
        p2.transform.translation = Vector3(x=0., y=2., z=0.)
        p2.transform.rotation = Quaternion(w=0.5, x=0.5, y=0.5, z=0.5)
        self.tf_broadcaster.sendTransform(p2)
        
        # Sleep after each timestep
        time.sleep(0.05)     
rclpy.init(args=None)
test_animator = TestAnimator()
rclpy.spin(test_animator)
```

Image:
[image: RVIZ illustration]
The bottom right axis is the origin (0,0,0). Point 1 is the point closest to the origin, and is rotated Quaternion(w=0.8, x=0.1, y=0.1, z=0.1) with respect to the origin axis as represented by the tilt of the axis on the picture. Point 2 is rotated Quaternion(w=0.5, x=0.5, y=0.5, z=0.5) with respect to Point 1, and is a vector from Point 1 equal to Vector3(x=0., y=2., z=0.).

Comment: "You also know the quaternion rotation from Point 2 to Point 1" Then aply the inverse rotation from point 1? Also with no code shown whatsoever, this is a pure math question at this stage so not fit for SO. [ask]

Comment: Hello. It would really help if you could make a drawing of the situation with the two vectors and the two rotations. As it stands, I don't understand how the first quaternion `w,x,y,z=0.8,0.1,0.1,0.1` relates to the problem?

Comment: @Julien I added a start of some reference code.

Comment: @Stef Point 1's rotation and position is with respect to the origin. I want to know Point 2's coordinates with respect to the origin as well.

Comment: I don't understand what "Point 1's rotation with respect to the origin" mean. A drawing would help.

Comment: @Stef I think you are right - the rotation of point 1 does indeed not matter. I am working on a drawing which I can post soon. But the idea is simple, I have a Point 1 that I know the x,y,z position of. And then I have a Point 2 which I know the rotation of with respect to point 1 (I can also find its rotation with respects to the origin), as well as the euclidean distance between point 1 and point 2. So it is basically following the rotation from Point 1 to Point 2 the euclidean distance.  Not sure how to actually code that though.

Comment: @Stef added an image. Starting to think there is infinite solutions to this as I can change the vector from Point 1 to Point 2 to match a euclidean distance of 2 with infinite number of solutions. But in a 2D situation it makes more sense to me. Given a point p1=(1,2) and a 2D rotation matrix from p1 to p2 (or origin to p2), I can find the angle p2 makes with respect to the positive x-axis by using the inverse tangent function. Then I can create a vector with length 2 "following" that angle, find its x,y coordinates, add the position of point 1 and I got point 2. 3D must be similar?

Comment: Your image is great, but could you please add legends on it or at least a few sentences explaining it? Where are point 1 and point 2 on the image? Where are the rotations?

Comment: @Stef The bottom right axis is the origin (0,0,0). Point 1 is the point closest to the origin, and is rotated Quaternion(w=0.8, x=0.1, y=0.1, z=0.1) with respect to the origin axis as represented by the tilt of the axis on the picture. Point 2 is rotated Quaternion(w=0.5, x=0.5, y=0.5, z=0.5) with respect to Point 1, and is a vector from Point 1 equal to Vector3(x=0., y=2., z=0.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253426/discussion-between-haakonflaar-and-stef).

Comment: If I were you. I would consider simple math. You can move your origin to point 1 by transform X. Then with your quartenion values from p1 ->p2 you can calculate p2 coordinates wrt. origin at p1...then simply...add them to get your final p2 wrt. original origin.....

Comment: @JasonChia Right, could you kindly provide/code the maths to do so using the example values I have written?

Answer (score 0):

Given your conditions.Logically you have a vector from origin to P1. Which is obviously [1,2,3] unless I am dumb. then you rotate this vector by quaternion p2 and extend by unit of 2. The simple approach would be to :

```
P1 = (1,2,3)


Q12 = (0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)
Equation: Length * unit vector of P1 * rotation matrix from quaternion
Set origin at P1. P2 wrt. P1 is given by 2*[1/6,2/6,3/6]*
[  0.0000000,  0.0000000,  1.0000000;
   1.0000000,  0.0000000,  0.0000000;
   0.0000000,  1.0000000,  0.0000000 ]

Giving you P2 wrt. P1 coordinates of [2/3,1,1/3]

And since P1 is actualy [1,2,3]+[2/3,1,1/3]

P2 wrt. origin is then simply [1.66,3,3.33]
```

QO1 is not necessary since the end point is simply [1,2,3].